# How can I run my function on document ready in Jquery

Tags: jquery, function

I created a some jquery code which gets some json data and displays it on the page. In order to reuse it, i wrapped it in a  function:

```
$(function(e) {
var answer;
id = 1;

var question = function() {
    $.getJSON('getjson.php?id=' + id, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    var $htmlString = "";
     $.each(data, function(index) {
        $htmlString += "<h2>" + data[index].question + "</h2>";
                str =  data[index].answer;
                 answer = data[index].answer.split(', ');

    $htmlString += "<ul>";
    for(var index in answer) {

       $htmlString += "<li>" + index + " : " + answer[Math.floor(Math.random() * answer.length)] + "</li>";

    }
    $htmlString += "</ul>";
    });$('#content').html($htmlString);
    });
};
});
```

Now, the first time the page loads, I need that function to run by itself, then when I click on 'next' the id increases and the function is triggered. 
The above function works great when I use the click trigger, but how can I trigger it right after the document is ready.

Thanks

Comment: *"The above function works great when I use the click trigger, but how can I trigger it right after the document is ready."* I'm not seeing you hook up the `click` event anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use:

```
$(function(){
  (question = function(){
    // your code
  })();
});
```

Comment: thanks, that did not work but (question)(); worked with is that same. thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure, try: `(question = function(){console.log('test')})();question();` in your firebug console, and it should work with two 'test' written, but anyway nice if you managed to get it worked ;)

Comment: my bad, might have messed up on copy and paste, now it does work exactly how you illustrated thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there. Because you're passing a function into `$()`, you're hooking up in a [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) handler (it's a [shortcut](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)). So just add a call to the function at the end:

```
};

question();

});
```

Also, you've said

> The above function works great when I use the click trigger, but how can I trigger it right after the document is ready.

...but I'm not seeing you hook that up anywhere. If you aren't, you'll also want to do that, e.g.:

```
    // Hook up click
    $("selector for elements to click on").click(question);

    // Call right now, since we're in a `ready` handler
    question();
});
```

Comment: although the click() function will work to bind click functions (for the most recent and probably the next few jquery versions), it is best practice to start using the on() function instead, please checkout http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: offcourse this is only true if you use jquery 1.7 and above :) (which i would advise you to use!)

Comment: @giorgio: I disagree that it's best practice (although `on` is fine), and not only is `click` not deprecated, I think it's very unlikely to be.

Comment: i retreat :) you are very right, click is _not_ deprecated, which i misunderstood, mea culpa. still i stick with the best practice part of my comment, at least as far as you'd want to bind the event to more than a single element, as it makes it easy to use event delegation which _really_ saves memory and will be a  lot faster when a lot of elements are concerned. At the bottom line; choose wisely

Comment: in think vitamin videos I seen that the click is a shortcut of on. when we use click jquery is really using on. so if you want to go strait to the pont, you should use on (You can see this on the jquery source file). Though, even if you use click jquery is quick to realise that we mean 'on'

Comment: @aurel: Yes. As of jQuery 1.7, `click` and the others are really just proxies for `on` (prior to that, they were just proxies for `bind`). The extra function call is not measurable in human terms; the shorter syntax is a style choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Your function definition, which you could minify here or keep in a separate file
...var question...

// Shorthand for the jquery document.ready
$(function() {
    // Code here to call custom functions
});
```